# Using multiple arcs to crop circle from image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I am trying to crop a circle out of 2 images and place them side by side like so:

```js
const ctx = $('#canvas')[0].getContext("2d");

const image = new Image();
image.onload = () => {
        const coords = [[115, 62.5], [495, 62.5]];
        const coords2 = [[65, 12.5] , [445, 12.5]];

        for(let i = 0; i < coords.length; i++) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(coords[i][0], coords[i][1], 50, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
            ctx.clip();
            ctx.drawImage(image, coords2[i][0], coords2[i][1], 100, 100);

        }
    };
image.src = 'https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=50&w=700&h=250&bg=afeafe';
```

```css
#canvas {
    border:1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="200"></canvas>
```

However, this is only cropping one of the images and the other one is not showing and I don't understand why?

When I comment out these lines

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(coords[i][0], coords[i][1], 50, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
ctx.clip();
```

It places the 2 images correctly, so the positioning is not the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by saving the context before clipping it and then restoring it after clipping it like so:

```js
const ctx = $('#canvas')[0].getContext("2d");

const image = new Image();

image.onload = () => {
 const coords = [[115, 62.5], [495, 62.5]];
 const coords2 = [[65, 12.5] , [445, 12.5]]
 for(let i = 0; i < coords.length; i++) {
     ctx.save();
     ctx.beginPath();
     ctx.arc(coords[i][0], coords[i][1], 50, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
       ctx.closePath();
       ctx.clip();
       ctx.drawImage(image, coords2[i][0], coords2[i][1], 100, 100);
       ctx.restore();
 }
};

image.src = 'https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=50&w=700&h=250&bg=afeafe';
```

```css
#canvas {
    border:1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="200"></canvas>
```